# Laravel - Disable Traits for Testing

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, factory, traits

I'm played around with Laravels Observers and Traits. Unfortunately I'm running now into a Problem during the generation of Fake-Data using the seeder or factory for phpunit.

Is there a way to disable Model specific traits during testing?

```
 6) Tests\Unit\Places\PostTest::a_post_belongs_to_one_place
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Genusshaus\App\Scopes\Places\PlaceScope::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, null given, called in /home/vagrant/smart/genuss/app/App/Traits/Places/ForPlaces.php on line 18
```

Cheers, Stan

Answer (score -4):

If you need to disable a model or trait during testing, then your code isn't well written. Please rewrite your code so it will always work and have the behaviour you would expect.

Comment: Hey Arjen, Thanks for your answer. To specify,  I'm Building a multi tenancy app so i've set specific middleware that needs a $place Model to be passed to every request or have it stored in the session. ( $request->place ?: session()->get('place') ) A model like a post or an event, can only be created when you are on a place instance. Each of these models have a ForPlaces Trait where i Set the logic behind that. So how can I pass now variables to to the factory request? Cheers, Stan